# Manga or manhwa about a male main character who arrives in a fantasy world with his mind linked with a female clone of himself

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I am trying to find a manga/manhwa I read a few years back, where I remember only parts of the plot. Sadly, I can't say whether it is a manga or an manhwa. Here's the plot:

A male main character (MC) with dark hair arrives in a fantasy world with his mind linked with a female clone of himself. They both appear to be wearing a dark blue or black uniform and emerge from a tiny clearing surrounded by trees and shrubbery. A knight style character and a group of adventurers he bumps into take him as a kidnapper and try and rescue his female self. Shenanigans happen and they explain themselves. The female MC goes with the knight guy to a city school to learn magic and the male MC goes with the adventurers to learn swordsmanship.

I don't know what else happens, as I stopped reading after that. Looking to find it again to find out more.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ***After Transformation, Mine and Her Wild Fantasy***. A Chinese manhua.

[image: Promotional art for "After Transformation, Her and Mine Wild Fantasy."]

Description:

> When other people experience a body transformation, it is inevitably either male to female or female to male.
>
> Me? I wake up to find myself transformed into two different bodies.
>
> Both a male body and a female body, one conscience operating two bodies, all sorts of embarrassing moments.
>
> Walking together normally makes other people think that I am sweethearts with my other-self, such sadness.
>
> Also, the entire business of a hero rescuing the beautiful maiden, I call Bull.
>
> I get slashed by a sword and my female body gets abducted, and he wants me to thank him?!?! Can it be less of a tragedy?

[Link to the Baka-Updates page](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/i2eqmbz/after-transformation-mine-and-her-wild-fantasy).

[And a link to the novel version too](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/after-transformation-mine-and-her-wild-fantasy/).

I'm 99% sure this is the one, the main character female part get kidnap by the knight in an unwanted rescue as early as the first few chapter. Both the male and female part is sharing the same mind, with one studying magic and the other studing swordmanship.

Comment: Looks like a good bet to me, though only the OP can confirm whether it's the correct answer or not. Hope you don't mind my edits.